# Google Drive is not access able in RELEASE apk android application?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am trying to accessing Google Drive from my own android application. I am stuck in a situation that my app is working perfectly in **DEBUG APK** but not working in **RELEASE APK**. Google drive is access able in debug apk but not in release apk. I am trying to create folder and upload any image in that folder.

I try to access google drive. I am able to access it in DEBUG mode but not in RELEASE mode. Again i have cross checked my SSH-1, it's correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.